# Why does `/etc/alternatives` being a symlink affect `apt`?

Tags: apt, symbolic-link, update-alternatives

I've got the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Step 1
RUN apt update && apt install -y wget

# Step 2
# All your persistent configs are in /root.
RUN mkdir -p /root/.symlinks/etc \
    && mv /etc/alternatives /root/.symlinks/etc/alternatives \
    && ln -sf /root/.symlinks/etc/alternatives /etc/alternatives

# Step 3
RUN wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/xpra.asc https://xpra.org/gpg.asc \
    && wget -P /etc/apt/sources.list.d https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xpra-org/xpra/master/packaging/repos/jammy/xpra.sources

# Step 4
RUN apt update
```

In step 2, I change `/etc/alternatives` into a symlink to another directory, in step 3 I install a program called `xpra`, and then in step 4 I run `apt update`. The final step 4 fails with the following error:

```
RUN apt update
Get:6 https://xpra.org jammy InRelease [4096 B]
Err:6 https://xpra.org jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 18ADB31CF18AD6BB
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: https://xpra.org jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 18ADB31CF18AD6BB
E: The repository 'https://xpra.org jammy InRelease' is not signed.
```

But if I were to omit step 2, which is changing `/etc/alternatives` into a symlink, then step 4 would work correctly.

Why would `/etc/alternatives` being a symlink affect `apt`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to occur because `/root` doesn't have the `x` bit set for other users. It is `drwx------`. So during `apt update`, it must be the case that a non-root user tries to execute a file from `/etc/alternatives`, which is actually `/root/.symlinks/etc/alternatives`, and it can't enter `/root` because `/root` doesn't have the `x` bit set for non-root users.

If I add the line `chmod +x /root` in between steps 1 and 2, then there are no more errors in step 4. But `/root` should remain `drwx------` for security reasons, so I wouldn't recommend this as a workaround.